# How to select data from multiple tables and display them in a json format?

Tags: php, mysql

I have many of the same tables. I need to get the data from each of the tables and bring them out in the json format:

```
[
  "table1": {
     ["first colomn value", "second colomn value", ...],
     ["first colomn value", "second colomn value", ...],
     ["first colomn value", "second colomn value", ...],
     ...
  },
  "table2": {
     //values from table2
  },
  ...
]
```

Is it possible to make a one request mysql? How then will the request and php code?

Comment: Fetch the data into an array of arrays and then dump it all with `json_encode()`. Where are you getting stuck with this?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Please try to solve this yourself, and if you get stuck come back with a *specific* question about what's not working, and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Madbreaks, I do not understand how to make mysql request. I hope I write php code itself.

Comment: @Havenard How make mysql request?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To do this in one request you would need a stored procedure, then iterate through your result set and iterate through your result. For portability your better off not using stored procedures, as they are not very portable.

heres some code i modified from http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php using PDO

```
<?php 
// dont forget to instantiate $conn
$sql = 'CALL multiple_rowsets()';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$jsonArr = array();
do {
    $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if ($rowset) {
        $jsonArr[] = tojson($rowset, $i);
    }
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());

$jsonData = "{";
$i = 0;

foreaeach ($jsonArr as $json)
{
   if($i !== 0) $json .=',';
   else $i = 1;
   $jsonData .= $json;
}    

$jsonData .= "}";

echo $jsonData; // your output

function tojson(&$rowset) {
    $json = '{';
    $p = 0;
    foreach ($rowset as $row) {
        if($p !== 0) $json .=',';
            else $p = 1;
        $json .= '[';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($row as $col ) {
            if($i !== 0) $json .=',';
            else $i = 1;
            $json .= $col
        }
        $json = "]";
    }
    $json.="}";
    return $json;
}
?>
```

this is untested but should give you an idea of how to do it

now for your stored procedure it should look like

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE multiple_rowsets()
   BEGIN
   SELECT *  FROM table1;
   SELECT *  FROM table2;
   SELECT *  FROM table3;
   END //
DELIMITER ;
```

But if you are ok with going to the database more than once, i would **highly** recommend just running each select from php, convert each result to json, pop each result in array, then iterate through to create one big json

Comment: table names not known in advance.

Comment: Than you couldnt possible do it in one transaction. You woould have your array of tables `$tables`, iterate through each table, store the results in an array and call `json_encode()` on the array like @ Havenard  said. for connecting to the database use http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

check the following query, it gives you the idea, this is just for one single table and it works. you can use union to have a summary of all tables ...

```
select concat("{", (select group_concat(concat('["', concat_ws('","', col1_name, col2_name, col3_name), '"]')) from your_table) ,"}") from dual;
```